# What are the theoretical limitations on using clever DynamoDB table design to eliminate the need for joins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, relational-database

Specifically, what are the simplest relational data access patterns such that if you wanted to use DynamoDB to reproduce them, you would sometimes be forced to use multiple sequential queries (or inefficient queries like scan) to get the data you wanted, no matter how cleverly you designed your table(s)? I'm thinking e.g. queries with multiple joins.

(Motivation for this question is reading https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/ and wanting to know how far the idea can be taken.)

Answer (score 1):

If you were forced to use multiple Queries or Joins then you would be in one of two situations:

1. Your schema is badly designed
2. You should not be using DynamoDB

For example, if you wanted all the items in your table that have a date between(x, y), that would not be possible in DynamoDB without a full table Scan, which could be inefficient.

You may also find some analytical style workloads (OLAP) difficult to implement.

I would encourage you to watch this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfxBhvGpoa0) which highlights the advanced access patterns and showcases whats truly possible.

Comment: With that date range example - assuming that the date field is the sort key for a secondary index then I think that doing a parallel scan (as described here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/scaling-writes-on-amazon-dynamodb-tables-with-global-secondary-indexes/) is probably efficient enough. I think this is a case where doing multiple queries isn't too inefficient because they can proceed in parallel (unlike the application-layer join problem where you have to query one table to figure out how to query another) - have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Proceeding in parallel can work, but imagine having 10TB of data. How many threads/processes would it require to Scan that entire data-set, and what would the cost be? How long would it take? Its an anti-pattern that should be avoided. Timeseries database would be much better suited.